# Android Canvas not rendering Framelayout

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a `FrameLayout` onto a canvas, but I can't get it to work. Drawing an `ImageView` works fine, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's an example of one way I'm trying to draw a `FrameLayout`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Context activity = this.getContext();

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams cellParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    ImageView cloud = new ImageView(activity);
    cloud.setLayoutParams(cellParams);
    cloud.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent_cloud_large);

    FrameLayout gameTile = new FrameLayout(activity);
    gameTile.addView(cloud);
    gameTile.layout(100, 200, 200, 300);
    gameTile.draw(canvas);
}
```

I'm also trying it without setting `LayoutParams` for the `ImageView`, and instead using: `cloud.layout(0, 0, 100, 100);`, but neither way works.

Here's my code for the `ImageView`, which does work.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Context activity = this.getContext();

    ImageView image = new ImageView(activity);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent_cloud_large);
    image.layout(100, 100, 200, 200);
    image.draw(canvas);
}
```

Do I need to override the `FrameLayout's` `draw` method in some way? Why doesn't it work out of the box?

I see that the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) say "The view must have already done a full layout before this function is called." Maybe that's my problem? How do I "do a full layout" on a `FrameLayout`?

Comment: why do you call FrameLayout.draw() in your custom View's onDraw () ?

Comment: The android canvas has no method to draw a view onto it. Instead, you call `.draw()` from the view, and pass in the canvas. There is no proper way to call `.draw()` outside of the `.onDraw()` method, because `.onDraw()` is the only method that gives you access to the `canvas` created from your custom view.

Comment: just add that FrameLayout to your UI hierarchy tree, it will draw itself so you don't need to call any View,draw method

Comment: I actually need to draw it onto a canvas, so I can add zoom and two-way drag scrolling. The canvas doesn't have a UI hierarchy like you're thinking of.

Comment: just extend ViewGroup or any subclass of ViewGroup and add your Views to that container, that's it

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. It was missing a call to `measure`. This is what I'm using in the end:

```
GameTile gameTile = square.getGameTile();
gameTile.measure((int)tilePixels, (int)tilePixels);
gameTile.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(coor.getX() * tilePixels, coor.getY() * tilePixels);
gameTile.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

`GameTile` is a subclass of `FrameLayout`. The `save`, `translate`, and `restore` methods are used to position the `FrameLayout` on the canvas.